# lib/Pages/ChattingPage.dart:15:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html' as html;

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, new-operator

I got this error when I was launching my app in the emulator does anybody know whats wrong sorry I am kind of new to android studio

```
lib/Pages/ChattingPage.dart:15:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

But I did everything correctly it's RIGHT THERE

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/Widgets/FullImageWidget.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/Widgets/ProgressWidget.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not import `dart:html` in app for mobile (android or iOS). Remove it.
If you want use it for web application, you can use conditional import explained [here](https://aschilken.medium.com/flutter-conditional-import-for-web-and-native-9ae6b5a5cd39).